# Ruby Make the script public

Tags: ruby, sinatra, token, spotify

First of all, I'm new in Ruby. I'm working with the Spotify SDK and it needs a token to swap with Ruby. I've managed to make the script run on `localhost` but now I want to make it public. What I've done is:

```
gem install sinatra
# and then
ruby spotify_token_swap.rb
```

How can I now make this service run on public in the easiest way? Would it possible to use Dropbox public folder or such?

Comment: What do you mean by "run on public"? Make it easier for other people to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to run your code publically (ie. have your Sinatra site accessible on the web) would be to use [Heroku](http://heroku.com). They have a good article on [Getting Started with Ruby](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby), which uses Sinatra.